# How can you use weightSum to both scale vertically and horizontally (mine doesn't work) android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

So I have a bunch of images (ImageViews) that I'm trying to scale appropriately depending on the user's device.

I have sucessfully scaled them horizontally (4 images get scaled equally depending on the user's screen) using weightSum.

I'm now trying to scale each column vertically so that in this example it takes up 50% of the screen but I'm not having any luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:weightSum="2"
    > 






        <!--  -->
        <!--  -->
        <!-- A new column -->
        <!--  -->
        <!--  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:weightSum="4"
            >  
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_1"
             />
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_2"
             />
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_3"
             />
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_4"
             />
        </LinearLayout>



        <!--  -->
        <!--  -->
        <!-- A new column -->
        <!--  -->
        <!--  -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:weightSum="4"
            >  
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_1"
             />
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_2"
             />
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_3"
             />
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/wallpaper_1"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/wallpaper_id_4"
             />
        </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Anyone deal with this before?
Thanks

Comment: Also Yes I know I have it all in a scrollview, the reason behind this is because eventually I wish to add maybe 15+ columns. I'm just trying to be able to scale each image depending on the user's device. Some devices a height of 50dp looks nice, on a tablet though that would be super small. Which is why I want to use weight sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first LinearLayout inside your ScrollView, height of `wrap_content` doesn't make sense if you're using weights. Use `fill_parent` or `match_parent` instead. That said, it doesn't exactly make sense to have a ScrollView around something like that and additionally nested weights tend to yield poor performance. You might want to consider using [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it doesn't really make sense to use a scrollview. The logic behind it is I want to display a bunch of images  but I also want them to be scaled depending on the device. And even though it contradicts what a weightSum does I wanted them to equal out bigger than the full screen that way you can scroll amongst them. So the thumbnails will be big, in my opinion bigger than a typical thumb nail.